# Method of sections - Is it compression or tension?

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-analysis, statics

I know how to do the method of sections, however I get a confused once I get an answer and move on to the next section.
[image]

For example this truss. I worked out joint A, AE = -84.9 AB = 60, but when I move onto joint E, and I have to use AE = -84.9, I get confused on whether EA and AE are the same or I have to change signs.

Answer (score 2):

Define: Force away from the joint is positive (+)

Draw the FBD as shown on the left, keep in mind that the member end force is the flip of the joint force with the identical magnitude, and the sum of the member end forces must be zero to maintain the static equilibrium of the member.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They should be the same. The sign of the value you get (positive or negative), means that the bar is in tension or compression respectively.